# Haskell Mutable Structure with Immutable Shell

Tags: arrays, haskell, io, monads, space

I'm pretty new to Haskell, so any help is appreciated!

I'm using an IOArray to update random elements in constant space. I have a wrapper that looks like this:

`data W = W{ arr:: IO (IOArray Int Node), n :: Int, ... }`

However, I can't find a way to update `arr` so that it's visible when the wrapper is being passed around without doing something like `wrappper{arr = x}`, which wastes a lot of GC time. In tests, it turns out to be too slow.

Is there any way to update `arr` so that it's globally visible? Thanks!

Comment: Mutable data in Haskell needs to be wrapped in a Monad, perhaps look to see if the `ST` monad isn't better suited for your needs

Comment: jozefg is right: there's also `STArray`, and note that `runST` can turn an `ST` action into a pure value.

Comment: `data W s = W{ arr :: STArray s Int Node, ...}`. Do I just have to create the array entirely before putting it in the wrapper? That could be a viable way of doing it

Comment: @Craig I've posted a quick example below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick example of how to use ST arrays

```
import Data.Array.ST hiding (unsafeThaw) -- Deprecated
import Data.Array (Array)
import Data.Array.Unsafe (unsafeThaw) -- If you really really really need it

newtype W a = W {arr :: Array Integer a}

modifyW :: a -> W a -> W a
modifyW v (W arr) = W $ runSTArray $ do -- The double $ is on purpose, . doesn't
                                        -- play so well with Rank n types.
  a <- thaw arr -- Turn `arr` into something we can modify
  writeArray a 1 v -- modify it
  return a
```

This will ensure the computation is pure, but the array will not be copied inside `modifyW`, all those modifications are constant time. If you can't afford any copying at all you can use `unsafeThaw`. But this is well.. unsafe. It'll actually modify the pure array so you have to be extremely careful not to try to use the pure structure after `modifyW` is run. This is much harder than it sounds thanks to lazy evaluation so I'd caution you against this.

With this style, you read from the pure `Array`, then when you need to modify it, you run in the `ST` monad which let's you do impure things, but won't let them bleed into the rest of your program.

Comment: That is amazing! I'll try my best to avoid these unsafe features down the road, but they're definitely a good way to get off the ground!

Comment: @Craig Don't go overboard :) Generally when you find yourself reaching for `unsafe*` you're doing something wrong. But yes, occasionally they are invaluable

Comment: @Craig "but they're definitely a good way to get off the ground!" I'd like to give a more forceful "no way!" response to this; I think `unsafe*` functions should be thought of as a (dangerously) accessible plugin interface to the internals of GHC. Strapping dynamite to your boots is also a good way to get off the ground :)

Comment: Yeah, it turns out that unsafe thaw doesn't play well with the optimizer, so I'll be doing this safely :)